# Undefined reading in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have a simple employee profile generator app.  Everything works just as expected up until the promise for generatePage(employeeData).  The console correctly logs employeeData but it is not getting passed to generatePage.  Does anyone have insight into why?  I have also included a picture of the beginning code for generate-page.js and the "undefined" console error message.

```js
const {writeFile, copyFile} = require('./utils/generate-site.js');
const generatePage = require('./src/page-template.js');
const mockData = [
    {
       // lots of mock data objects here 
    },
]
let employeeData = mockData;

function init() {
    return inquirer.prompt(questions.startQuestions);
}
function getEmployeeData(answers) {
    if (answers.role === 'Engineer') {
        let engineer = new Engineer (
            answers.name,
            answers.id,
            answers.email,
            answers.role
        )
        return getEngineerData(engineer);
    } else if (answers.role === 'Intern') {
        let intern = new Intern (
            answers.name,
            answers.id,
            answers.email,
            answers.role
        )
        return getInternData(intern)
    } else if (answers.role === 'Manager') {
        let manager = new Manager (
            answers.name,
            answers.id,
            answers.email,
            answers.role
        )
        return getManagerData(manager)
    } 
}

function getEngineerData(engineer) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve (
            inquirer.prompt(questions.engineerQuestions)
            .then ((response) => {
                    engineer = {...engineer, ...response};
                    // console.log(engineer)
                    employeeData.push(engineer)
                }
            )
        )
    })
}
function getInternData(intern) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // same as getEngineerData function
    })
}
function getManagerData(manager) {
       return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // same as getEngineerData function
    })
}
function confirm() {
    return inquirer.prompt(questions.confirmQuestion)
}

function buildTeam() {
    init()
    .then(answers => getEmployeeData(answers))
    .then(confirm)
    .then(response => response.confirmAdd ? buildTeam() : console.log(employeeData))
    .then(employeeData => generatePage(employeeData))
    .then(pageHTML => {
        return writeFile(pageHTML)
    })
    .then (writeFileResponse => {
        console.log(writeFileResponse);
        return copyFile()
    })
    .then(copyFileResponse => {
        console.log(copyFileResponse);
    })
    .catch (err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
buildTeam();
```

[image: undefined console reading at page-template.js]

Comment: I believe you've created an infinite loop right here `.then(response => response.confirmAdd ? buildTeam() : console.log(employeeData))`. This is supposed to call `buildTeam()` over and over again, and so it never actually goes through to what you believe is the problem. Try commenting out the problematic part and see if it goes into an into an infinite loop.

Comment: you can't just assign out side of a promise to expect that to work. you have to keep the chain going.

Comment: Another point about the same line @kmp mentioned: `buildTeam()` has no return value, so it will always result in `undefined`. `console.log` also always returns `undefined`. Therefore `employeeData` in your next `.then` is always going to be `undefined`.

Comment: unfortunately even when I comment out both those lines for confirm and then response I still get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"

Comment: Actually I meant to imply that everything below the mentioned line should be commented out, but anyways @David784 has a great point. You return undefined since `buildTeam()` is of `void` type. You should use `async/await` to make your life easier with promise return values.

Comment: You have seven (7) chained then's. Avoid promise hell https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/how-to-get-out-of-promise-hell-8c20e0ab0513.

Comment: Thank you all! I was able to see the problem with the return statements and fixed it with ` .then(response => {
        if (response.confirmAdd) {
            buildTeam()
            return employeeData
        } else {
            return employeeData
        }
    }) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.log returns "undefined" so the solution was to return the employeeData array in the promise chain to pass on.

```js
 .then(response => {
        if (response.confirmAdd) {
            buildTeam()
            return employeeData
        } else {
            return employeeData
        }
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).